# customize the titleformat of chapters

Tags: fonts, chapters

The below code is used to customize the chapter and section while writing a thesis which is in book environment. The problem I am having is I am unable to customize the fonts size of chapters and chapters title. Please can anyone put forward a solution

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setappendix}{Appendix~\thechapter}
\newcommand{\setchapter}{Chapter~\thechapter~} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\sffamily\bfseries\huge\color{black}}{}{0.5ex} %
{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{appendices}=0
    \setappendix
    \else
    \setchapter
    \fi 
    \filleft \\%
    \titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{1ex}%
#1\filleft\\
    \vspace{1ex}%
    \titlerule[3pt]}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{ \color{black}\sffamily\bfseries\huge}{}{0.5ex}%
{ \titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{1ex}%
    #1\filleft
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{}{#1}\\
    \vspace{1ex}%
    \titlerule[3pt]}
\makeatother

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{-10ex}{0ex}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0.0ex} %
{\sffamily\color{black} \thesection~#1 \filright}[\smallskip]

\titleformat{name = \section, numberless}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0.0pt}%
{\sffamily\color{black}#1\filright}[\smallskip]

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\Large}{}{0.5ex}%
{\color{black}\thesubsection~#1\filright}[\smallskip]

\titleformat{name = \subsection, numberless}[hang] {\sffamily\Large}{}{0.5ex}%
{\color{black}#1\filright}[\smallskip]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please  post a compilable code? Also, what exactly do you have in mind with ‘customize the fonts size’?

Comment: Please don't post sniplets. Post something that others can just copy and test as is. We have no idea which document class you are using etc. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: I want written 'chapter 1'  of size 16 without bold whereas chapter tiltle e.g 'custamize font size' in bold plus in 24